# How to secure REST service that login from third parties

Tags: rest, openid, openid-provider

I have a REST service that my mobile app uses to authenticate when the users click on the Facebook or Google icons.

The service accepts the user's id from the provider and checks if it exists on the database and then issues the access_token to be used for the other methods.

The problem is that I just thought that it could be pretty easy for someone to intercept the calls and discover which service authenticates and what the user id is and then call it with to get a token.

How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to separate the **authentication** and **authorization** functions.  You can let Google ([Google Sign-In](https://developers.google.com/identity/)) handle authentication.  If you follow the API they will securely **authenticate** the user and send you the token which you can validate.

Once you know who they are for sure, your site can safely **authorize** that user approriately.  For example, they might be an existing user, need to make an account, be an administrator.  You can make those **authorizations** on your site based on the user authenticated by Google (in my example).

[Twitter](https://dev.twitter.com/web/sign-in), [Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login) and others do the same.  Also see [OpenID Connect](http://openid.net/connect/faq/).